# Fail to resume Jenkins build when it got stuck due to node got disconnected

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins, cicd

I have one situation that i am running selenium web ui test cases using jenkins in node machine, I want build strong solution that if the currently running build stuck due to node got disconnected then it should wait until disconnected node comes up and then it should resume the execution where it got stucked.

Is there any way to implement this solution using groovy script or using any plugins in jenkins ?

I have tried some suggestions from internet, but it didn't get worked well.

Comment: _I have tried some suggestions from internet_: Can you tell us about those suggestions?

Comment: Like I have created this groovy script and add this script to the build section of the Jenkins job :

Comment: Here is the groovy script link : https://inextrix-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/p/admin/EUbRkDAsSrdJnRDCayjYGdoBIv3uTzhR2beFjJUnDF86Sg?e=z5Wt31

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "**Node Stalker**" plugin. This plugin allows Jenkins to keep track of disconnected nodes and automatically resume the build once the node becomes available again.

If the Node Stalker plugin doesn't meet your requirements or you prefer an alternative approach, you can implement a custom solution using Jenkins Pipeline and Groovy Script.

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'your-node-label' }
    stages {
        stage('Run Tests') {
            steps {
                script {
                    try {
                        // Your Selenium test execution command or script here
                        sh 'your-selenium-test-command-or-script.sh'
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        echo "Node disconnected! Waiting for node to come back online..."
                        nodeWait()
                        echo "Node is back! Resuming test execution..."
                        // Retry the Selenium test execution command or script here
                        sh 'your-selenium-test-command-or-script.sh'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def nodeWait() {
    // Wait for the node to come back online, check its status every 10 seconds
    timeout(time: 30, unit: 'SECONDS') {
        waitUntil {
            return isNodeOnline()
        }
    }
}

def isNodeOnline() {
    // Check if the node is online
    def node = Jenkins.getInstance().getNodeByFullName('your-node-name')
    return node != null && node.toComputer() != null && node.toComputer().isOnline()
}
```

Comment: Hello, @yashaswi k, the script provided by you is not actually resume the execution, it will actually trigger new build once node will comes up. and I haven't find **Node Stalker** plugin in Jenkins from available plugin.